# Counting repeated tokens in ANTLR4

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I am writing a simple "language" in ANTLR4/JavaScript which can associate numbers to variables and print them. This works fine but after extending the print statement to take one *or* many variables I don't figure out how to get the count of them. (I am using a visitor, not listener, but am interested for both.)

Grammar:

```
print   : 'print' ID (',' ID)* ';' ;
```

How do I find out how many ID tokens there are?

Currently I hacked something together as follows:

```
visitPrint( ctx ) {
    let i = 0;
    let c = undefined;

    while( (c = ctx.ID(i)) ) {
        let val = ctx.ID(i++).getText();
        print( this.variables[val] );
    } 
}
```

Shouldn't there be a better way to do this, like some count() method?

Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `visitPrint` method you get a `PrintContext` with a member `ID()`. This returns an array and you can simply use `context.ID().length` to get the ID count (note: no parameter).

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for :)

Comment: If my answered helped then pls accept it (the big checkmark on the left). If you found an answer particularly useful then you can also upvote it (also on the left the answer text).

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot upvote at the moment because I have too few points yet, but marked it now as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an `id` parser rule:

```
id
 : ID
 ;
```

and then use this `id` rule in all other parser rules instead of the `ID` token, then you can override the `visitId` function:

```js
visitId(ctx) {
    // Check ctx.ID() here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't this just move the problem - then I deal with ctx.ID() in a separate rule but I still have to visit one or more id's then in  visitPrint(ctx).

Comment: For every call to `id` the `visitId(...)` function will be called, so you wouldn't need to loop yourself. If this is not what you want, consider updating your original question with some extra info because it is unclear to me what you're after then.